# Finding roots of $z^3 = 8$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble finding the cubed roots of $8$ as a complex number.

$$z^3 = 8+0i$$
$$z^3 = r^3 e^{3\theta i}=8e^{2i\pi k},\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$

$$\implies r=2,3\theta = 2\pi k\implies \theta = \frac{2\pi k}{3}$$

$$z=2e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{3}}$$

I would think I have then $$z=2,2e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},2e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}$$

But the answer says: $z=2,-1+\sqrt{3}i, -1-\sqrt{3}i$

What's going on?

Comment: i think they simplified $2\cos(\frac{2\pi}3)= -1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^3-2^3=(z-2)(z^2+2z+4)=0$

So first term has solution $z=2$. 
Now-

$z^2+2z+4=0$

$\frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4-16}}{2}=z$
So, $z=-\sqrt{3}i-1 \ and\ z=\ \sqrt{3}i-1$

Comment: This is really clever

Comment: Thanks, just a tip but I think you should study from KhanAcademy, a very good site IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

Comment: So they just subbed in my values into that, and spat out those results?

Comment: Yep. OR It's used so often that most people remember the cube roots of unity as $1,w,w^2$.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks!